# CountDownTimer in Animation

Tags: android, countdowntimer

this is the code I use in countdowntimer.

```
mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());

ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    mDetector.onTouchEvent(arg1);
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        AnimationDrawable loadingAnimaton;
        loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) ImageView.getBackground();

     }loadingAnimation.start();

        }.start();
    return true;  
}});
}   
}
```

--the error I get on the `loadingAnimation.start();` saying that
    Syntax error on token "start", Identifier expected after this token

any alternative way to set my countdown numbers into images.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have 2  `start()` calls and both look wrong.

Try this

```
       CountDownTimer ct=new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        AnimationDrawable loadingAnimaton;
        loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) ImageView.getBackground();
        loadingAnimation.start();
     }


  }
  ct.start();
```